# How to manipulate the ajax response text

Tags: ajax, httpresponse

I've an ajax code like this:

`var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open('GET', 'http://www.example.org/', false);
req.send(null);

if(req.status == 200)

    var response = http_attendance.responseText;
                        document.getElementById('divAttendance').innerHTML = response;`

When I get result on the page, FF browser shows the DOM elements on 'divAttendance'. If I want to put put some jquery effect on the result, I can't be able to do it.

DOM elements is clearly viewed using firebug. But, when I generate the source code of that page then there is no repsonse text on 'divAttendance'. It is blank like thisL:

```
<html>
....
..
<div id="divAttendance"></div>
..
..
</html>
```

How to manipulate or put some effect on that result ???

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using jQuery then you should be using jquery ajax anyways 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Regardless, if you are populating your div with AJAX response then it will not show up using "View Source" rather you will have to use a tool like firebug.

Your div initially should look like following

```
<div id="divAttendance" style="display:none"></div>
```

and your javascript should have the following

```
.....
document.getElementById('divAttendance').innerHTML = response;
$("#divAttendance").show("slow");
```

For such operations jQuery load is easy and usefull function, have a look at 
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Your specific example can be rewritten as

```
<html>
....
IMPORT JQUERY.JS
<script language="javascript">
$('#divAttendance').load('http://www.example.org/', function() {
 $("#divAttendance").show("slow");
});     
</script>
..
<div id="divAttendance" style="display:none"></div>
..
..
</html>
```

Comment: I think you have not clearly understood my question ..

I've only used ajax in this.

Ajax will give me some result then I showed it up on div having id="divAttendance"

The div contains the result which is in table format.

I want to put some effect like hover the table row using jquery but I can't see the effect of it on that table. 
When I view the source code: the div doesn't contain any value. But the actual source should be like this :

<code><div id="divAttendance"><table><tr><td>SNo</td><td>Name</td>....
</table></div>
</code>

Comment: How do you do view source? and what is your expected output in HTML source?